# Refactoring ideas wanted

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-web-api

I have a several WebApi controllers have that use 2 generic classes for processing.  Depending on the data sent in the request, one of the generic classes is called.  This logic is wrapped in a Try/Catch, which is used to handle timeouts, authentication failure, and system errors.  When I started to look at the GET and POST actions, it's basically the same code.  I was trying to see how I might refactor this so there isn't duplicate code. The Post is mostly identical, except the list of requests is provided.  This is screaming for refactor so I don't have this in 5 different controllers, each with a different workflow generic.   Any suggestions on a refactor?  I would like to try to encapsulate the exception logic in to a common location that each controller would use.  I don't want to add it to the workflow, since I don't want a workflow coupled to a calling method that is a Web Request.

Here's a sample of what the code looks like.

```
private IRequestWorkFlow<RequestTypeA, MyResponse> _WorkFlowA;
private IRequestWorkFlow<RequestTypeB, MyResponse> _WorkFlowB;

public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] RequestTypeA aRequest, [FromUri] RequestTypeB bRequest)
{
    try
    {
        if (!aRequest.IsEmpty())
        {
           var requests = new List<RequestTypeA> { aRequest };
           var aResponses = _WorkFlowA.ProcessRequest(requests);
           return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Ok, aResponses);
        }

        var bRequests = new List<RequestTypeA> { bRequest };
        var bResponses = _WorkFlowB.ProcessRequest(bRequests);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Ok, bResponses);
    }
    catch (TimeoutException ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout, ex.Message);
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, ex.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Unable to process your request.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess first of all you should extract your Try/Catch code to a method accepting `Func<HttpResponseMessage>` and put your method body there.

Comment: @Smiech  Yeah, I'd love to have a single place for Try/Catch, so the controllers can't have different responses to the same issue.  I'll see if I can't extract the logic and put it in a base class.

Comment: Best approach would be to adopt SRP and dependency inject what you need. The smaller the "lego" pieces, the more code reuse you get, plus a more robust framework as a general outcome. Not always, but generally true.

Comment: @Code4Life,  I'm using DI to inject the workflows. My project i'm working on is a complete refactor of the WebApi to be completely inject-able and unit test each component.  This is the last area where I just wasn't seeing a way to refactor the exception logic in to a single spot.

Comment: Then I think you should edit your question to be more specific about what you wanted.

Comment: I've added more to the question, asking more specifically what I'm hoping to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom attribute. Something like this.

```
[OnException]
public class HomeController { .... }   

public class OnException: ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is TimeoutException)
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout, ex.Message);
        if (context.Exception is UnauthorizedAccessException )
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, ex.Message);
        if (context.Exception is Exception)    
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Unable to process your request.");
    }
}
```

You can remove the try/catch and OnException will handle it.

Comment: This worked great.  An added benefit is that the filter is added int the WebApiConfig, so developers don't need to remember to change to a custom base class.  The code needed a small change to work.  The method returns void, so you can't return the Request.  I changed "return Request..." to "context.Request..." and then just did a return.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't test the code but glad it worked since missed the void. 

Answer (score 1):

You could edit the method like that in your base class:

```
HttpResponseMessage Try(Func<HttpResponseMessage> method)
{
    try
    {
        return method.Invoke();
    }
    catch (TimeoutException ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout, ex.Message);
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, ex.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Unable to process your request.");
    }  
}
```

Comment: This looks interesting. I have done a generic like this before.  I'm going to give this a try.

Comment: Since in this case you're tied to HttpResponseMessage because of exception handling I edited my answer